# How to introduce a delay in actions for my Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I wasn't successful in searching the internet for what I am trying to accomplish (probably because I dont know what I need!). I so far have developed a quiz game that has several different modes and a 60 second timer for each questions. My only issue remaining, is that I do not know how to introduce a 2-3 second delay between questions being delayed on the screen. Right now, is the user gets the questions right or wrong, the next question instantly appears on the screen. What I would like to happen, is that the screen goes blank (I'll just cleack the text blocks with [xyx.Text = " ";] with exception of a text block that will display "Right!" or "Wrong!" for a period of about 3 seconds.

After the 2-3 seconds, the program will continue as normal, randomly selecting a question to display on the screen. For clarity here is my current code I'm using

```
public sealed partial class QuickPage : Page
{
 DispatcherTimer timeLeft = new Dispatcher();
 int timesTicked = 60;

public void CountDown()
{
    timeLeft.Tick += timeLeft_Tick;
    timeLeft.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
    timeLeft.Start();
}

public void timeLeft_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    lblTime.Text = timesTicked.ToString();

    if (timesTicked > 0)
    {
        timesTicked--;
    }
    else
    {
        timeLeft.Stop();
        lblTime.Text = "Times Up";
    }
}
```

Here is a thread where i got help with the DispatcherTimer I am using for the countdown timer:[Help with DispatcherTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858277/issue-with-dispatchertimer-for-a-countdown-clock)

Comment: After the countdown of 60 seconds (timesTicked), start a new timer with a timespan of 3 seconds. After 3 seconds a timerX_Tick event will be fired and the application can go to the next question.

Comment: To be clear, I should create another DispatcherTimer maybe called (briefPause)

Comment: Yes, that's right! :) (Update: Answer added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with 5 seconds delay:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

// Call this method after the 60 seconds countdown.
public void Start_timer()
{        
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    bool enabled = timer.IsEnabled;

    // Check and show answer is correct or wrong

    timer.Start();       
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop(); // Or you can just call timer.Stop() if the timer is a global variable.

    // Clear screen, go to the next question
}
```